# Java : autoboxing of an Object array of integers, cast to int from LinkedList.toArray()

Tags: java, casting, autoboxing

I would like to use code similar to the following:

```
int letterIndex[];
LinkedList<Integer> letterList;
```

...

```
if(!letterList.isEmpty()) letterIndex = (Integer[])letterList.toArray();
```

However, it is not allowed, and apparently the cast to `Integer[]` is not autoboxed when converting to `int[]`. How would I accomplish the equivalent without declaring `letterIndex` as `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`?

Comment: final int s=list.size();int[] r=new int[s];for(int i=0;i<s;i++); r[i]=list.get(i); //dear goodness, what the world has come to?

Comment: Obviously... but I was looking for something provided by the class library.

Comment: it's not possible to take a `java.util.Collection` and transform it for a primitive array. To put it simply: the generic type doesn't exist during runtime (and actually practically doesn't exist on compile time). To do that you'd need some method w/ a signature like that toArray(Collection<? extends Number> c, Object array) and the array should be of a primitive type. The code cannot be even optimized properly and to work efficiently the JVM would need to expend some very special care and all that for a single line of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to create a new array and assign each value from the `Integer[]` array.

Apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(wrapperArray)`.

Comment: so basically it would be more straightfoward to use an ArrayList instead? I just hate using them since they seem so inefficient.

Comment: @TurtleToes well, it depends. There is no 'obviously more efficient way'. But I think that's microoptimization in most cases.

Comment: I suppose I will just create the integer array dynamically by the size of the list and step thru it to convert each index. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bozho, actually it's hard to imagine such tasks make it to a popular library.

Comment: @bestsss - I didn't get what you mean :)

Comment: @Bozho, I mean converting a collection to a primitive array. It's a single liner (more or less) and if you have to do it, something has gone wrong probably. Boxing primitives is more or less inefficient but well, ok. Converting them (the boxed ones)back to a primitive array usually it's an uncommon task to me.

Comment: @bestsss when some APIs are incompatible it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using primitives?

Can you change it to:

`Integer[] letterIndex;`

Comment: he was explicit he does not want that.

Comment: You are right. In a real-world application I probably would use an Integer[] array. However, I am fairly new to Java and I'm probing the extents of what I can do and how to do it.

Comment: *In a real-world application I probably would use an Integer[] array.* That's a bad decision

Comment: In the class I was designing, the values were declared final, so an Integer[] array would have served just as well. The code to create the array was in a constructor. However, either way, the class is pointless, and is just me poking my away around the language.